# List unversionned files added after a specific date

Tags: git

Using a git repository :

Is there a way to list all the unversioned files that have been added (created) after a given date ?

Edit : I'm on a windows machine. But I can use command such as grep or find or any command built in http://cmder.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for a in $(git ls-files --others); do  find $a -mmin +120 -exec echo "$a was modified more than 120 minutes ago" \; ; done
```

To break that apart:
      `git ls-files --others`: List all untracked files
      `find $a -mmin +120`: Check if the file was last modified 120 minutes ago

But I am not certain that answers your question if you were asking how to filter untracked files by when they were *first untracked*.